# Does $\overline{\text{span}\{x_n\mid n\geq 1\}}\neq H$ imply $x_1\notin \overline{\text{span}\{x_n\mid n\geq 2\}}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a linearly independent family in a Hilbert space $H$.

Assume that $\overline{\text{span}\{x_n\mid n\geq 1\}}\neq H$.

> Is it enough to conclude that $x_1\notin \overline{\text{span}\{x_n\mid n\geq 2\}}$?

This fact is used [here](http://archive.schools.cimpa.info/anciensite/NotesCours/PDF/2006/Zuazua.pdf) (p. 142) for $H=L^2(0,T)$ and $x_n=e^{-n^2 \pi^2 t }$. Is it a general result or depends on this particular setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer the question about those notes. The title question of course has counterexamples.

It looks to me like that statement is indeed a non sequitur. The version of Müntz's theorem quoted as "Theorem 2.6.3 (Münz)" [sic] does not say anything about the closed linear span except that it's not the whole space. A sequence in a Hilbert space is minimal if and only if it has a biorthogonal sequence - the thing that section aims to demonstrate - so this is quite a significant point.

However, the usual proof of Müntz's theorem does show that $x_m$ is not in the closed linear span of $\{x_n\mid n\neq m\}$. One direction of Müntz's theorem "away from the origin", e.g. in $L^2[e^{-\pi^2T},1]$, in fact proves that the distance of the monomial $s^{m^2}$ from $\operatorname{span}\{s^{n^2}\mid n\neq m\}$ is bounded away from zero. By a change of variables $s=e^{-t}$, which is (bi-)Lipschitz on this range, this gives a lower bound on the distance in $L^2[0,T]$ of $e^{-m^2\pi^2t}$ from the span of $\{e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\mid n\neq m\}$. Sorry, I don't have a reference to hand.

Comment: In fact, according to those notes it seems that **(i)** $x_m\notin\overline{\text{span}\{x_n\mid n\neq m\}}$ is a consequence of **(ii)** $\overline{\text{span}\{x_n\mid n\neq m\}}\neq L^2(0,T)$, which is not the case in general as shown in the other answer. So, I agree it seems non sequitur.

Comment: And if we go to the given reference for the "Münz Theorem" (which is [Schwartz book](http://archive.numdam.org/article/THESE_1943__259__1_0.pdf), p. 23) we discover that **(i)** is indeed given as part of the Theorem:   "[...] le système est non total, **mais libre**, dans $L^p(0,1)$ [...]". For some reason this part of the statement was omitted in those notes.

Comment: [This](http://cyber.sci-hub.bz/MTAuMTA5MC9xYW0vNTEwOTcy/10.1090%40qam%40510972.pdf) earlier paper, which probably is the source of the proof in those notes, also gives the Schwartz book as reference for both facts, **(i)** and **(ii)**.

Answer (score 1):

It's not general. Let $y_n(k)=1$ if $k=n$, 0 otherwise. Let $z_n=y_{n+1}$ for $n\ge 1$ and let $x_n=z_n$ for $n>1$ and $x_1=\sum_{n>1} \frac1n x_n$. This is in $\ell_2(\mathbb N)$ which is isomorphic  to $L_2$.

Comment: Do you understand why it is true for the particular case in the post?

Comment: They're everywhere positive, so certainly not orthogonal to each other in $L^2$.